# How to update the vectors in a std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> without copying?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, unordered-map

How to extend the below code to collect the all `entry.score` and not just keep the most recent one?

The code I have right now is:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, float> container;

int main() {
    // some code
    for (auto entry : entries)
        container[entry.name] = entry.score;
}
```

How to extend it to keep all `entry.score` whilst avoiding copy?:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<float>> container;
//vectors need to be updated using .push_back(entry.score)

int main() {
    // some code
    for (auto entry : entries)
        container[entry.name] = ;  //missing connection
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`container[entry.name]` returns a `std::vector<float>&`. `std::vector` exposes `push_back`, which inserts an element into the vector.

Therefore you can do:

```
container[entry.name].push_back(entry);
```